# Version-sensitive ObsoleteAttribute

Tags: .net, attributes

The [`[Obsolete]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute is very handy for marking classes that have been deprecated in favor of better implementations, but it isn't sensitive to the version of .Net that the project is targeting.

For example, say I'm using a home-rolled `ThreadSafeDictionary` class for versions of .Net before 4.0. When .Net 4.0 came out it included a new class called [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). I'd like to be able to mark `ThreadSafeDictionary` as `[Obsolete]` but **only** if the project is being compiled for .Net 4.0. It doesn't appear that the stock `ObsoleteAttribute` supports controlling the compiler's warnings by framework version.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Pedantic maybe, but if a method is obsolete it's obsolete on all versions - if you're compiling for 2.0, it's still obsolete really! (They should upgrade to get access to the more appropriate class)

Comment: I can't always upgrade every program to the latest-and-greatest framework. For example, we have a middleware platform that must go through extensive QA before its certified to use the latest version of the framework. In the meantime, we have to be able to deploy on .Net 3.5 while developing new projects/branches that will eventually deploy on 4.0

Comment: Lawrence: That doesn't mean it's not obsolete; it is often the case that we are constrained to use an obsolete version. I work with the ATG e-commerce framework, and that was only certified to run on Java 1.6 over a year after Sun end-of-lifed Java 1.5. Crazy times.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could roll out your custom attribute and then create a post-build process that examines the compiled code through reflection searching for your attribute.

Comment: Possibly using a custom FxCop rule